# How can I parse HTML in batches using xpath [PHP]?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, domdocument

I tried all sorts of things but couldn't find a solution.
I want to retrieve elements from html code using xpath in php.

Ex:

```
<div class='student'>
 <div class='name'>Michael</div>
 <div class='age'>26</div>
</div>
<div class='student'>
 <div class='name'>Joseph</div>
 <div class='age'>27</div>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the information and put them in an array as follows:

```
$student[0][name] = Michael;
$student[0][age] = 26;
$student[1][name] = Joseph;
$student[1][age] = 27;`
```

In other words i want the matching ages to stay with the names.

I tried the following:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpathDom = new DomXPath($dom);
$homepostcontentNodes = $xpathDom->query("//*[contains(@class, 'student')]//*[contains(@class, 'name')]");`
```

However, this is only grabbing me the nodes 'names'
How can i get the matching age nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is only grabbing the nodes `name` - you are telling it to!

What you will need to do is in two steps:

1. Pick out all the student nodes
2. For each student node, pick out the columns

This is a pretty standard step in linearization of data, and the XPath queries are simple:

## Step 1

You pretty much have it:

```
 $studentNodes = $xpathDom->query("//div[contains(@class, 'student')]");
```

This will return all your `student` nodes.

## Step 2

This is where the magic happens. We have our nodes, we can loop through them (`DOMNodeList` implements `Iterator`, so we can `foreach`-loop through them). What we need to figure out is how to find its children...

...Oh wait. `DOMNode` implements a method called `getNodePath` which returns the full, direct XPath path to the node. This allows us to then simply append `/div` to get all the div direct descendents to the node!

Another quick foreach, and we get this code:

```
$studentNodes = $xpathDom->query("//div[contains(@class, 'student')]");
$result = array();
foreach ($studentNodes as $v) {
// Child nodes: student
$r = array();
$columns = $xpathDom->query($v->getNodePath()."/div");
foreach ($columns as $v2) {
           // Attributes allows me to get the 'class' property of the node. Bit clunky, but there's no alternative
    $r[$v2->attributes->getNamedItem("class")->textContent] = $v2->textContent;
}
$result[] = $r;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Full fiddle: http://codepad.viper-7.com/t868Wh

Comment: right! i was trying ways to loop thru student and you just gave me the answer i was looking for. thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShiggySteez: No problem. If this was what you were looking for, feel free to accept it as best answer.